# Unity. The class doesn't save field value from its method

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I pass Vector3 parameter from external class to the method. Then assign it to class field. Then when I want to check class field value from the Update method it says it is zero. What am I doing wrong?

```
 using System.Collections;
 using System.Collections.Generic;
 using UnityEngine;
 
 public class CustProjectile : MonoBehaviour
 {
 
     Vector3 direction;
     

     private void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other)
     {
         Destroy(gameObject);
     }
 
     public void InitiateProjectile(float speed, Vector3 direction)
     {
         Debug.Log(direction + "= PARAMETER FROM METHOD");
 
         this.speed = speed;
         this.direction = direction;
       
 
         Debug.Log(this.direction + "= VALUE IN THE CLASS");
     }
 
     private void Update()
     {
         Debug.Log(this.direction + "= VALUE IN THE CLASS FROM UPDATE METHOD");
         var dir2 = transform.position + direction;
         
         transform.position += dir2 * speed * Time.deltaTime;
       
     }
 
 }
```

This is method that passes Vector3 parameter

```
public void AnimationShootProjectileAttack()
{

// projectile is a prefab

var bullet=Instantiate(projectile, transform.position+new Vector3(0,7f,0), Quaternion.identity);
var bullet_c = bullet.GetComponent<CustProjectile>();

projectileDirection= transform.TransformDirection(Vector3.forward);
bullet_c.InitiateProjectile(10f, projectileDirection);
```

}

[image: Console log]

Comment: Are you sure this is the same instance of this class? Could you include where you call he method from?

Comment: Also in general why do you add the `transform.position` twice? `transform.position += dir2 * speed * Time.deltaTime;` basically results in `transform.position = transform.position + (transform.position + direction) * speed * Time.deltaTime;` is this intended?

Comment: Are you sure you aren't changing the Vector outside the code? You don't make a copy in InitiateProjectile, you just store a reference.

Comment: @PalleDue [`Vector3`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Vector3.html) is a **struct** ;)

Comment: Oh, sorry. It looked like a class to me ;-)

Comment: I suggest you use `Debug.Log(this.direction + "= VALUE IN THE CLASS FROM UPDATE METHOD", this);` etc .. this allows you to click on a log message and it will highlight according object in the Hierarchy / Assets ... From your code it looks like it should work but I still believe that the instance you call the method on is not the same as the one running `Update`

Comment: @derHugo, Added calling method. I messed around with transforms until I until I found that the problem wasn't them.

Comment: @derHugo, just did that. With one projectile on the scene. All three times the same gameObject in th Hierarchy was highlighted

Comment: @derHugo, https://youtu.be/DQeni3IfQvw

Comment: Is this your actual code for `CustProjectile`? I see that e.g. `speed` is missing as well ... just to be sure there is nothing else influencing the `direction` value

Answer (score 0):

I found out what the problem was. When instance of CustProjectile was created its property Vector3 compiled LATER than the method giving its value. I don't know how is that possible but it is cuz there would be no field to give value to but…

Actually, I decided to recheck that again just to be sure and I CAN'T reproduce the error I had in the question. Eh…

Comment: `compiled LATER` .. that makes little sense ;) All your code is compiled before you can even run it ;)

Comment: wrong word, more accurately would be "that part executed". Sorry if I'm being misleading I just really don't know what happened.